# Changed locale screwed up Microsoft Word password protection

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, passwords, microsoft-word-2011

I'm in France, and changed the operating system locale to France. All good, until today I tried to open a password protected Word 2011 doc, and got this message:

"*This document has been password protected with an encryption scheme not available in this region*".

Any thoughts on how to fix the problem - apart from changing the locale back to US?

Comment: I'd expect keyboard character problems, but this sounds like a concerning bug...

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that in France, 128-bit password protection used to be
illegal. However, it is very puzzling why Word 2011 still maintains
this law which was repealed in the year 2000.

You could try these workarounds :

1. Ensure that your Office is fully patched.
2. Set your locale to Canada-French.
3. Most people solve this problem by opening the document with
   LibreOffice and re-saving it.
4. Update to a later version of Office.

Answer (score 1):

> Any thoughts on how to fix the problem - apart from changing the locale back to US?

You will want to change the locale back, remove the password, then change the locale and set a password.  This will change the password scheme to one supported by your locale.

While this isn’t a perfect answer since it involves changing the locale, you can also change the locale to one where the password scheme is supported, then simply change it to current locale

Answer (score 0):

The problem disappeared when I upgraded to Word 2016. The password protected document opened fine.

Thanks to those who answered and commented.